# Prove there are uncountably many open singletons in $ω_1$

Tags: general-topology

Given a well order $(W,≤)$, where $W$ is uncountable, and $$ω_1:= \{x\in W: \text{only countably many } y \in X \text{ s.t. } y \le x\},$$ prove there are uncountably many open singletons in $ω_1$.

I haven't learn anything about cardinals yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W'\subseteq W$ be the set of all elements s.t. there exists an uncountable number of smaller elements. $W'$ is nonempty and has a minimum, let's say $w_1$ (in order to avoid the more natural $\omega_1$ that is already used in the question). Any element less than $w_1$ contains only countably many smaller elements, so there are uncountably many elements that coutain only countably many smaller elements.

If there were only countably many open singletons smaller than $w_1$, that would mean that there are uncountably many elements $x$ smaller than $w_1$ s.t. $\{x\}$ is not open; let's call such $x$ a "limit point". However, for $x$ a limit point, $x+1$ is an open singleton and not a limit poin ($x+1$ is defined to be the smallest element of $W$ larger than $x$). So there are at least as many open singletons as limit points in $[0, w_1)$ and we got a contradiction: so there can't be only countably many open singletons smaller than $w_1$.

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you Peter!

Comment: Nicely laid out, Peter. +1

Answer (score 2):

Every successor ordinal is an open singelton.

Comment: Is there any other way without resorting to ordinals?

Comment: You are not resorting to ordinals. Just replace "successor ordinal" by "successor element".

Comment: Ok, does that has to be immediate successor element?

Comment: What does that mean

Comment: b is a immediate successor of a, if $a\lt b $ and there is no c s.t. $a\lt c\lt b$

Comment: They are the same thing

Comment: I see, thank you very much Rene!