# why is successor ordinal open in omega_1?

Tags: general-topology

I saw some arguments from the following link, 
[Prove there are uncountably many open singletons in $ω_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849827/prove-there-are-uncountably-many-open-singletons-in-%CF%89-1/849830#849830)
But, I still can not figure out why it is open. What kind of open interval is it located in?

The definition is: b is a immediate successor (successor ordinal) of a, if a is smaller than b, with no c between a and b.

or, a similar condition,
[image]

Why is the minimum point an open set?

Comment: You can also write a successor ordinal as $\alpha + 1$. Have you an idea how to write $\{\alpha+1\}$ as an open interval?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: What is the largest ordinal smaller than every element of $\{\alpha+1\}$?

Comment: α? (Sorry, I am really new to this material, and we have not discussed ordinal in class.)

Comment: Right, and the smallest larger?

Comment: α+2?So you mean it is in (α, α+2)?

Comment: Well, what elements does $(\alpha,\alpha+2)$ contain?

Comment: only α+1 is contained in that interval?

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer to that linked question? It seems not to talk about ordinals (which you haven't discussed, and are seemingly unfamiliar with), and just give an answer. If you want an answer which pertains specifically to what Rene wrote, then by studying a bit about ordinals you can easily deduce the answer yourself.

Comment: Yes, they just state the conclusion, but do not give the reason. And that is why I ask it here. So is α+1 the only element in (α, α+2)?

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple , take the open interval,$$(\alpha,\alpha+2)=\{ \alpha+1\}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still have a question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850904/prove-there-are-uncountably-many-singletons-in-%CF%891-that-are-not-open       For the answer here, the author let x′ be the first element of ω1 immediately after this infinite sequence. And he claim {x′} is not open. Would you please explain the reason here? Why such a singleton set is not open?

Comment: I don't quite understand his argument "any open set that contains x′ must contain all but finitely many of the xn's"...

Comment: I mean what is the difference between these 2 situations. (The question I asked and the linked.) They both seem to be the first thing after a countable set. But one is open, the other is not.

Comment: Never mind. I have asked this part in another question.